# Return decoded base64 string as image on browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing a GetByID method in my controller,

```
public string GetByID(string id)
    {
        var currentData = Db.ReadAll<FileItem>();
        int index = currentData.FindIndex(t => t.ID.Equals(id));
        byte[] dataURIArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(currentData[index].DataUri);
        string base64ImageRepresentation = Convert.ToBase64String(dataURIArray);

        return base64ImageRepresentation; 
    }
```

I manage to return the base64 string when I call the ID, but i want a way that i return the actual image(or any file) in the browser.

Comment: what do you mean "return in the browser"? display the image?

Comment: Are you wanting to display the image as a entire page result or as a element inside the page?

Comment: Also, not related to your problem but change your code to `FileItem item = currentData.First(t => t.ID.Equals(id)); byte[] dataURIArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(item.DataUri);` and you will find better performance. If you are using EntiryFramwork replacing the `.ReadAll<FileItem>` to putting the Where clause there will increase your performance even more.

Comment: i want to display it as an entire page result if possible, as in display image

Comment: Then why have the base64 string? Why not just return the `byte[]` from the function? Then just use any example on the internet of "Display byte[] as image on web page" or "Return byte[] as file from web page"

Comment: Are you using ajax btw?

Comment: When you say "return", do you mean "show"?  Is this base64 string part of a JSON response?  Are you sure you don't want to just create a URL that references a way to get the image that you could just plug into an image tag?  You could certainly use a data URI to directly create an image from base64 encoded data on your page but that's mainly good for small images.

Comment: Im uploading files, i get an item made up of  metadata and the base64 files, i save the base64 and replace it with the path in the item, then i save the item in a list and write the list in a json. Im trying to get the image back, so im reading the json, decoding it and getting the path from the .DataURI, so i want the user to have the option to put the ID in the api url and get the actual image back